# Need help/advice for changing code for date and time selection

Tags: php

I have a PHP page with a Due Date and Time selection option. What I would like to be able to do is limit the times in the time selection drop down to only show available working hours rather than a 24 hour time list from 00:00 to 24:00. Here is the code as it currently appears, but this is over my head and beyond my basic editing abilities. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciate. Thanks in advance,

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">Due Date:</td>
    <td>
        <i>Time is based on your time zone (GM <?=$thisuser->getTZoffset()?>)</i>&nbsp;<font class="error">&nbsp;<?=$errors['time']?></font><br>
        <input id="duedate" name="duedate" value="<?=Format::htmlchars($info['duedate'])?>"
            onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;calendar(this);" autocomplete=OFF>
        <a href="#" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;calendar(getObj('duedate')); return false;"><img src='images/cal.png'border=0 alt=""></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <?php
         $min=$hr=null;
         if($info['time'])
            list($hr,$min)=explode(':',$info['time']);
            echo Misc::timeDropdown($hr,$min,'time');
        ?>
        &nbsp;<font class="error">&nbsp;<?=$errors['duedate']?></font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: could you give me an example of what you need?

Comment: Yes, currently when selecting the time field, it generates a drop down list of times from 00:00 to 23:45 in 15 minute increments. All I really want to show in that list are times from 07:00 to 17:00, and even just 30 minute increments would be fine, we never break anything down farther than by the half hour.

Comment: Hey, you should consider using "<?php" is not good to use "<?="; read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated, use `<div>`/`<span>` instead

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

**Best code:**

```
function timeRange($start, $end, $interval="30 mins" , $outputFormat = null )
{
    $range = array();
    $start = strtotime($start); 
    $end   = strtotime($end);

    $current    = time();
    $interval   = strtotime('+'.$interval, $current);
    $diff       = $interval-$current;


    while ($start <= $end)
    {
        if( is_null($outputFormat) )
        {
            $range[] = $start;
        }else{
            $range[] = date( $outputFormat , $start);
        }
        $start += $diff;
    }
    return $range;
}
$times = timeRange('8:30', '17:30', '30 mins' , "H:i");
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08:30
    [1] => 09:00
    [2] => 09:30
    [3] => 10:00
    [4] => 10:30
    [5] => 11:00
    [6] => 11:30
    [7] => 12:00
    [8] => 12:30
    [9] => 13:00
    [10] => 13:30
    [11] => 14:00
    [12] => 14:30
    [13] => 15:00
    [14] => 15:30
    [15] => 16:00
    [16] => 16:30
    [17] => 17:00
    [18] => 17:30
)
```

**Simple code:**

```
function timeInterval( $start , $end , array $interval = array() )
{
    $list = array();
    for( $i = $start; $i <= $end ;$i++ )
    {
        foreach( $interval AS $min )
        {
            $list[] = sprintf("%02d",$i). ":" . $min;
        }
    }
    return $list;   
}


highlight_string( print_r( timeInterval( 8 , 17 , array( "00" , "30" ) ), true ) );
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08:00
    [1] => 08:30
    [2] => 09:00
    [3] => 09:30
    [4] => 10:00
    [5] => 10:30
    [6] => 11:00
    [7] => 11:30
    [8] => 12:00
    [9] => 12:30
    [10] => 13:00
    [11] => 13:30
    [12] => 14:00
    [13] => 14:30
    [14] => 15:00
    [15] => 15:30
    [16] => 16:00
    [17] => 16:30
    [18] => 17:00
    [19] => 17:30
)
```

And your HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">Due Date:</td>
    <td>
        <i>Time is based on your time zone (GM <?php echo $thisuser->getTZoffset();?>)</i>
        &nbsp;
        <font class="error">
            &nbsp;<?php echo $errors["time"];?>
        </font>
        <br/>
        <input id="duedate" name="duedate" value="<?php echo Format::htmlchars($info["duedate"]);?>" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;calendar(this);" autocomplete="OFF" />
        <a href="#" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;calendar(getObj('duedate')); return false;">
            <img src='images/cal.png'border=0 alt="">
        </a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="time">
            <option value="">Select you time...</option>
            <?php
            foreach( timeRange('9:30', '17:30', '30 mins' , "H:i") AS $time )
            {
                echo "<option value=\"$time\">$time</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        &nbsp;<font class="error">&nbsp;<?php echo $errors["duedate"];?></font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Bye!

Comment: I will take a look at it when I get a chance and let you know how if it works. Thanks for taking the time to look at it for me.